# How can I display the categories and subcategories in my admin form like in the product page?

Tags: magento2.3, layout, adminhtml, xml, category-listing

I am trying to add the categories and subcategories in a small panel **Exactly** like the one in the product panel
[image: like so]

and I want to add it in here instead of this XML field like the "toOptionArray" [image]

Heres my Xml file, i want to add it as the child of the `<formElements> </formElements>` [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Add into your UI Componet File**

```
<field name="category_ids">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\CategoryList</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Categories</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_ids</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Config/Source**

**CategoryList.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as CategoryCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class CategoryList implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    const COMPONENT_NEWS_CATEGORY_ID = '2';

    protected $categoryCollectionFactory;
    protected $request;
    protected $parentCategoriesTree;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getCategoriesTree();
    }

    protected function getCategoriesTree()
    {
        $getParentCateroyId = $this->getCategoryId();
        if (!$getParentCateroyId) {
            $this->parentCategoriesTree = [];
            return $this->parentCategoriesTree;
        }
        if ($this->parentCategoriesTree === null) {
            $storeId = $this->request->getParam('store');
            /* @var $matchingNamesCollection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
            $matchingNamesCollection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

            $matchingNamesCollection->addAttributeToSelect('path')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['neq' => $getParentCateroyId])
                ->setStoreId($storeId);

            $shownCategoriesIds = [];

            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
            foreach ($matchingNamesCollection as $category) {
                foreach (explode('/', $category->getPath()) as $parentId) {
                    $shownCategoriesIds[$parentId] = 1;
                }
            }

            /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
            $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => array_keys($shownCategoriesIds)])
                ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'is_active', 'parent_id'])
                ->setStoreId($storeId);

            $categoryById = [
                $getParentCateroyId => [
                    'value' => $getParentCateroyId,
                ],
            ];

            foreach ($collection as $category) {
                foreach ([$category->getId(), $category->getParentId()] as $categoryId) {
                    if (!isset($categoryById[$categoryId])) {
                        $categoryById[$categoryId] = ['value' => $categoryId];
                    }
                }

                $categoryById[$category->getId()]['is_active'] = $category->getIsActive();
                $categoryById[$category->getId()]['label'] = $category->getName();
                $categoryById[$category->getParentId()]['optgroup'][] = &$categoryById[$category->getId()];
            }

            $this->parentCategoriesTree = $categoryById[$getParentCateroyId]['optgroup'];
        }

        return $this->parentCategoriesTree;
    }

    public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId
        );
    }

    public function getCategoryId($storeId = null)
    {
        return self::COMPONENT_NEWS_CATEGORY_ID;
    }
}
```

> **After creating and updating the above files run the below command:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can make it like a radio button? as in only one option selected?
And how I can make only level 2 categories selectable? for example: Gear>bags>handbags, I want only bags or handbags to be selectable while gear SHOWS but CANT be selected

Comment: you can prepare the category array as you want in CategoryList.php file. And for single select replace multiselect -> select in UI file.

Comment: You don't have to create your own custom class for this, there is a perfectly fine option provider available in core Magento: `Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options`. If you want the custom filtered list of Categories as you said in the comments you do need the custom Model.